# Ruby: unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end for if statement

Tags: ruby

I was working with Java for a few months and am transitioning back to Ruby now. I am getting a weird error from the following code:

```
def count_divisors
  divisor_hash = {}
  25.times do |i|
    divisor_hash[i] = find_dividends(i)
  end
  puts divisor_hash
end

def find_dividends(i)
  count = 0
  1000.times do |k|
    if i % ( k + 1 ) == 0
      count++
    end
  end
  count
end
count_divisors()
```

This code is generating the following error:

```
test.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
test.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

This error does not occur when I remove the `if` statement. I am not sure why. I know every `if` statement needs an `end` statement, for some reason it seems upset by the placement of that `end` statement though.

Comment: Simple typos are off-topic on SO, plus, this question has already been asked and answered dozens of times.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't care if it is asked 1 million times. I didn't know up until yesterday, and I am sure there are going to be more people who don't know in the future. SO is a learning experience, stop being so rigid

Comment: On SO, there should be a single canonical question with a single canonical answer which is helpful for everyone. Duplicate questions are bad, because they spread the knowledge across several places. Typo questions are bad, because they are not generally useful, they are only useful to the asker. That's the opinion of the community, anyway, and I tend to agree.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `count++` to `count += 1` Ruby does not support incremental operator.